# Cambiar de palabras a numeros c++

Tags: c++, programación-funcional, programación-bajo-nivel

Estoy haciendo un curso de C++ y la verdad no encuentro la solución a este problema. Debo transformar caracteres a número ya sea enteros o decimales.

Ejemplo:

El usuario introduce "mil doscientos cincuenta" yo debo transformar eso a enteros y poder hacer operaciones como sumar o restar.

He intentado con switch case para cuando escriba x cadena de texto le agregue x cantidad de enteros a otra variable y luego ya hacer las operaciones, pero no acepta tipo de dato string, intentaría con if pero no es un código muy limpio, No hay otra forma de hacerlo?.

Ahora estoy intentado con if:

```
if(a == "mil")
{
   b += 1000;
}
else if(a == "novecientos")
{
   b += 900
}
```

Ahí ya imaginate el resto así con diferentes números ahora el problema es que solo me detecta la primera palabra:

"mil novecientos" pero solo devuelve 1000 no se porque.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pon que has intentado

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pon el codigo que tienes hasta ahora

Comment: Cual es el rango de numeros que analizarias, pq tampoco vas a analizar un rango muy amplio me imagino?

Comment: de unos 1000 minimo

Comment: Te devuelve solo 1000 porque en una secuencia `if/else if/else` en el momento que se cumple una condición (en este caso el `if`) ejecutara su código dentro y saltara cualquier `else if` o `else` de la misma secuencia.

Comment: Entonces que recomiendas para solucionar el problema

Comment: En un rato te doy el código, tengo la respuesta pero en c#, debo llevarla c++

Comment: Gracias, por favor mándalo lo antes posible o dame un explicación de cómo funciona.

Comment: Socio, yo invertí tiempo en responderte por lo menos merezco saber si la respuesta te sirvio, no crees? Ya te lo he preguntado varias veces y no dices nada, es una cuestión de respeto a un desconocido que decidió ayudarte

Comment: Perdón es que no había visto la verdad me sirvió ya te di Mi voto pero no te aparecen porque tengo menos de 15 de reputación, pero de todas formas gracias.

Comment: Víctor, para marcar la respuesta debes dar clic en el checkmark que sale abajo de los votos, si tienes dudas me avisas

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *unidades[9] = {"uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve"};
    const char *diez[9] = {"once", "doce", "trece", "catorce", "quince", "dieciséis", "diecisiete", "dieciocho", "diecinueve"};
    const char *veinte[9] = {"veintiuno", "veintidós", "veintitrés", "veinticuatro", "veinticinco", "veintiséis", "veintisiete", "veintiocho", "veintinueve" };
    const char *decenas[9] = { "diez", "veinte", "treinta", "cuarenta", "cincuenta", "sesenta", "setenta", "ochenta", "noventa" };
    const char *centenas[9] = { "ciento", "doscientos", "trescientos", "cuatrocientos", "quinientos", "seiscientos", "setecientos", "ochocientos", "novecientos"};
    char numeral[200];
    int numero = 0;    

    cout<<"Escriba en texto cualquier numero: \n";
    fgets(numeral, 200, stdin);
    
    if ((strlen(numeral) > 0) && (numeral[strlen(numeral) - 1] == '\n'))
    {
        numeral[strlen(numeral) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    char *token = strtok(numeral, " ");

    while(token) 
    {
        if (strcmp(token, "y") != 0)
        {
           if (strcmp(token, "cero") == 0)
           {
              numero = 0;
           }
           else if (strcmp(token, "cien") == 0)
           {
              numero = 100;
           }
           else if (strcmp(token, "mil") == 0)
           {
              numero = 1000;
           }
           else
           {
              for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
              {
                 
                 if (strcmp(unidades[i], token) == 0)
                 {
                    numero = numero + i + 1;
                    break;
                 }
                 else if (strcmp(diez[i], token) == 0)
                 {
                    numero = numero + (i + 1) + 10;
                    break;
                 }
                 else if (strcmp(veinte[i], token) == 0)
                 {
                    numero = numero + (i + 1) + 20;
                    break;
                 }
                 else if (strcmp(decenas[i], token) == 0)
                 {
                    numero = numero + ((i + 1) * 10);
                    break;
                 }
                 else if (strcmp(centenas[i], token) == 0)
                 {
                    numero = numero + ((i + 1) * 100);
                    break;
                 }
                 else if (strcmp(token, "mil") == 0)
                 {
                    if (numero == 0)
                    {
                       numero = 1;
                    }

                    numero = numero * 1000;
                    break;
                 }
              }
           }
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    cout<<"El número es: \n";
    cout<<numero;

    return 0;
}
```

Declaramos **5 arreglos**:

**unidades**: tendrá el numeral de los números del **0** al **9**.

**diez**: tendrá el numeral de los números del **11** al **19**.

**veinte**: tendrá el numeral de los números del **21** al **29**.

**decenas**: tendrá el numeral de los múltiplos de **10** desde el **10** hasta el **90**.

**centenas**: tendrá el numeral de los múltiplos de **100** desde **100** hasta **900**.

El **arreglo veinte** es un caso especial ya que las reglas de escritura del **21 al 29** son diferentes al resto, por ejemplo **21 se escribe como veintiuno**, mientras que **31 se escribe como
treinta y uno**, igual pasa con el **arreglo diez** cuyas reglas de escritura entre el rango **11** al **19** son completamente diferentes a cualquier otro intervalo numérico.

Después de declarar estos arreglos declaramos la **variable numeral**, que será la que contendrá el texto que escribamos como entrada para transformarlo a número.
Declaramos también la **variable numero** que será la que tendrá la transformación del texto al número que representa ese texto.

Después vendría la parte donde entraríamos el número por teclado. Una vez que entremos el número como texto por teclado y apretemos la **tecla enter** para comenzar el algoritmo, haremos uso de la **función strtok**, la cual nos va coger el número entrado como texto e irá analizando palabra por palabra de ese texto.

Posteriormente vamos analizando cada palabra que no tenga como valor la letra **"y"**, y preguntamos por casos especiales como el **"cero"**, **"cien"** o **"mil"**, cuya transformación será directa.

En caso de no cumplirse ningún caso especial, entonces preguntamos si esa palabra se encuentra en alguno de los arreglos antes declarados, en caso de encontrarse en alguno de esos arreglos pués se hace el cálculo correspondiente y se va actualizando la **variable numero**.

Por último se imprime el contenido de la **variable numero** que sería el texto convertido en un número.

Acá un ejemplo:

Supongamos que escribimos **"ciento cuarenta y tres"**, se verifica que no se cumple ningún caso especial, es decir **"cero"**, **"cien"** o **"mil"**, por tanto se procede a buscar cada palabra de lo escrito en cada arreglo a la misma vez. Se empieza por la primera palabra que es "ciento", y se verifica que se encuentra en la primera posición del **arreglo centenas**, como en **C++** los arreglos comienzan en la posición **0**, debemos aumentarle **1** al índice, es decir el cálculo correspondiente sería:

```
numero = numero + ((i + 1) * 100);
```

O sea:

```
numero = 0 + ((0 + 1) * 100);
```

Como el valor del **indice i** es **0** se incrementa en **1** y se multiplica por **100** ya que se encontró en el arreglo que se refiere a las **centenas**.

Ahora la **variable numero** vale **100**, pero seguimos; la próxima palabra es **"cuarenta"** y se encuentra en el arreglo de las **decenas**, en la cuarta posición, por tanto:

```
numero = numero + ((i + 1) * 10);
```

O sea:

```
numero = 100 + ((3 + 1) * 10);
```

Al valor previo que tenia la **variable numero** le hacemos el cálculo referente a las decenas, ahora el valor de la **variable numero** es **140**.

Después vendría la palabra **"y"**, por lo que esta palabra es intrascendente y no se hace nada, posteriormente vendría el análisis de la última palabra escrita que es **"tres"**, y se encuentra en el **arreglo de las unidades**, por tanto:

```
numero = numero + i + 1;
```

O sea:

```
numero = 140 + 2 + 1;
```

Y ahora el valor de la **variable numero** es **143** que es el resultado final.

**Ojo:** Mucho cuidado con las tildes, ya que si cometes faltas ortográficas a la hora de escribir, el algoritmo no funcionará como debe.